Wifi Driver for Ubuntu 20.04 having kernel 5.15.0-107-generic
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4090]
    Kernel modules: wl
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51e8] (rev 01)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for shoaib: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:6001154000-6001157fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 4c:d7:17:6a:d1:61
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-107-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:70804000-70804fff memory:70800000-70803fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@3:4
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 5a:7a:10:76:60:14
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-107-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.24.206 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair

This is my configuration of my Dell Laptop 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1355U × 12 having 5.15.0-107-generic kernle version .
please suggest how can i install wifi driver and HDMI port driver on this device.
Thank you
